# SSH Restrict User Access

Tags: centos, ssh, filesystems, security, access-control

When I ssh into the machine as webmaster I ssh into the correct chroot directory `var/www/domainname/public_html` but I can still access the entire filesystem.

I have changed the home ssh directory of webmaster successfully.   Now I want to restrict webmaster access to the home directory.  I started following [this](https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-ssh-user-to-directory-using-chrooted-jail/) article.  I am failing Step 5: Testing SSH with Chroot Jail because when I ssh from webmaster on my laptop into the main server with webmaster account.  Webmaster can still see the entire filesystem.  Should only see /var/www/domainname/public_html/

When I `cat /var/log/secure | egrep webmaster` I see successful connections to the server however nothing in relation to the chroot directory. `sshd[22528]: Accepted password for webmaster from ip port # ssh2`

I added the following lines in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
#define username to apply chroot jail to
Match User webmaster
#specify chroot jail
ChrootDirectory /var/www/domainname/
```

Here are the file permissions in the directory I want webmaster restricted to.

```
drwxr-xr-x.   8 root root   4096 Dec 17 19:37 archive
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root 964536 Jan 11 11:00 bash
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root 964536 Jan 11 11:01 bin
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root     33 Jan 11 11:04 etc
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root      6 Jan 11 11:03 lib64
drwxr-xr-x. 237 root root  12288 Dec 22 15:40 node_modules
crw-rw-rw-.   1 root root   1, 3 Jan 11 10:58 null
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root    545 Dec 22 15:56 package.json
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root 111876 Dec 22 15:40 package-lock.json
drwxr-xr-x.  10 root root   4096 Jan  3 15:18 public_html
crw-rw-rw-.   1 root root   1, 8 Jan 11 10:58 random
drwxr-xr-x.   4 root root     27 Dec 30 12:02 src
crw-rw-rw-.   1 root root   5, 0 Jan 11 10:58 tty
crw-rw-rw-.   1 root root   1, 5 Jan 11 10:58 zero
```

Comment: Check syslog on the server host for any messages from `sshd` about the chroot directory. If you still need help, please [edit] your question to include the relevant lines from your `sshd_config` file and the file permissions for the chroot directory (`/var/www/domainname/public_html/`) and its parent directories.

Comment: the syslog didn't show anything relevant to chroot directory, editing main question.

Comment: I have completed steps 1-4.  I realized the first time did the steps I was making dir /home/test when I should have been making dir /var/www/domainname/ so I re-did steps 1-4 and still came to the same conclusion.  I can ssh in as webmaster but can see the entire filesystem.  No errors or warning.  Logging in with webmaster yes.

Comment: yes restarted ssh server at end of step4.  path is /var/www/domain/pulic_html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118328/discussion-between-roaima-and-jesse-william-mac-dougall).